# Pagination with google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have several questions regarding how to do pagination with gae. test code:

```
    for i in range(0, 6):
        MyClass(myProperty=unicode(i)).put()
    q = MyClass.all()
    cursor = None
    print
    haveMore = True
    batchSize = 2
    i = 1
    while haveMore:
        print 'Batch', i
        i = i + 1
        result_set = q.with_cursor(start_cursor=cursor).fetch(batchSize)
        for obj in result_set:
            print obj.myProperty
        cursor = q.cursor()
        print cursor
        haveMore = True if len(result_set) == batchSize else False
```

output:

```
Batch 1
0
1
E9oBTgoMdGVzdGJlZC10ZXN0GgdNeUNsYXNzIUNVUlNPUiFqHWoMdGVzdGJlZC10ZXN0cg0LEgdNeUNsYXNzGAIMggENCxIHTXlDbGFzcxgCDOABABQ=
Batch 2
2
3
E9oBTgoMdGVzdGJlZC10ZXN0GgdNeUNsYXNzIUNVUlNPUiFqHWoMdGVzdGJlZC10ZXN0cg0LEgdNeUNsYXNzGAQMggENCxIHTXlDbGFzcxgEDOABABQ=
Batch 3
4
5
E9oBTgoMdGVzdGJlZC10ZXN0GgdNeUNsYXNzIUNVUlNPUiFqHWoMdGVzdGJlZC10ZXN0cg0LEgdNeUNsYXNzGAYMggENCxIHTXlDbGFzcxgGDOABABQ=
Batch 4
```

Questions:

1. First of all, how is the result set advancing when the same cursor is being used in different iterations of for loop?
2. How to fix the edge case? The for loop should terminate after 3 iterations. Batch 4 is empty.
3. How to page in reverse direction in gae (i.e., go back instead of next)?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here [Query with paging by cursor causes error because of limitations for "IN filter" in cursor() method... What should be the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014657/query-with-paging-by-cursor-causes-error-because-of-limitations-for-in-filter-i/6016575#6016575)