# How to page the dataset

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-templates, pagination

Hi I want to enable web pagination that used to work and it broke during an update to the environment or my implementation (not sure which). I want to paginate a list ordered by GAE 
Since objects tend to have a "natural ordering" ie time, numbers, words etc could this code be already available somewhere usable? I tried doing something like the example from Joey G that Google listed here: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/paging.html
My effort that takes the parameter called bookmark from the URL query:

```
  next = None
  bookmark = self.request.get("bookmark") 
  category = self.request.get('cg')#category parameter
  if bookmark:
    bookmark = datetime.strftime(bookmark[:-7], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  
  else:       
    bookmark = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 

  if cg: 
    articles = Articles.all().filter("category =", cg).filter("modified >", timeline).filter("published =", True).filter("modified <=", bookmark ).order("-modified").fetch(PAGESIZE+1)
```

It used to work and now the paging is broken, perhaps because I don't completely understand how to handle the modified and datetime objects. Could you help me on the way? The URL to my use case is www.koolbusiness.com/li
Thanks

EDIT/UPDATE: Here's the current code that displays the list page. It only uses `IN` at a few places so supposedly it could get rewritten to work without `IN` the difficulty is that it branches so much due the the many combinations possible ie searching with or with nocategory, category with or with no search and also geospatially but I don't think that I'm trying something impossible it's just that a need to learn more python (there is lambda programming involved that I only pasted in and don't fully grasp) and get a clearer structure when all the combinations are handled.

```
class I18NListPage(FBBaseHandler,I18NHandler):

  def get(self, cursor=None, limit=60, PAGESIZE = 10, twittername = None):
    client = OAuthClient('twitter', self) 
    if client.get_cookie():
      info = client.get('/account/verify_credentials')
      twittername = info['screen_name']
    if (users.is_current_user_admin()):
       timeline = datetime.now () - timedelta (days = limit)   
    else:
        timeline = datetime.now () - timedelta (days = limit)
    logo = ''             
    if util.get_host().endswith('.br'):
      cookie_django_language = 'pt-br'
      logo = 'montao'   
      translation.activate(cookie_django_language)
      self.request.COOKIES['django_language'] = cookie_django_language
      dispatch= 'template/montaoli.html'
    else:
        cookie_django_language = self.request.get('cookie_django_language', '') if self.request.get('cookie_django_language', '') else self.request.get('hl', '')
        dispatch= 'template/li.html'
    if cookie_django_language:
      if cookie_django_language == 'unset':
        del self.request.COOKIES['django_language']
      else:
        self.request.COOKIES['django_language'] = cookie_django_language
      self.reset_language()       
    next = None
    bookmark = self.request.get("bookmark") 
    if not bookmark:
       bookmark = = str(time.time())

    category = self.request.get('cg')
    q = self.request.get('q').encode("utf-8")
    w = self.request.get('q')
    cg = self.request.get('cg')
    t = self.request.get('t') 
    f = self.request.get('f')

    if cg and not t and not q and not f:#category without search
        ads = Ad.all().filter("category =", cg).filter("modified >", timeline).filter("published =", True).filter("modified <=", bookmark ).order("-modified").fetch(PAGESIZE+1)    
    elif q and not t and not cg and not f:#search without category
        ads = Ad.all().search(self.request.get('q')).filter("published =", True)    
        ads = filter(lambda x: x.modified > timeline, ads)
        ads = filter(lambda x: x.modified <= bookmark, ads)
        ads = ads[:PAGESIZE+1]
        ads = sorted(ads, key=lambda x: x.modified, reverse=True)
        #iterate list keeping elements that are on timeline newer than bookmark
    elif q and not t and cg and not f:
        ads = Ad.all().search(q).filter("type =", 's').filter("category =", cg).filter("modified >", timeline).filter("published =", True).filter("modified <=", bookmark ).order("-modified").fetch(PAGESIZE+1)    
    elif t and not f:
        ads = Ad.all().filter("type =", 'w').filter("modified >", timeline).filter("published =", True).filter("modified <=", bookmark ).order("-modified").fetch(PAGESIZE+1)    
    elif f == 'c':
        ads = Ad.all().filter("company_ad =", True).filter("modified >", timeline).filter("published =", True).filter("modified <=", bookmark ).order("-modified").fetch(PAGESIZE+1)
    elif f == 'p':
        ads = Ad.all().filter("company_ad =", False).filter("modified >", timeline).filter("published =", True).filter("modified <=", bookmark ).order("-modified").fetch(PAGESIZE+1)
    else:
        if util.get_host().find('onta') > 1:
            ads = Ad.all().filter("modified >", timeline).filter("published =", True).filter("url IN", ['www.montao.com.br','montao']).filter("modified <=", bookmark ).order("-modified").fetch(PAGESIZE+1)              
        else:
            ads = Ad.all().filter("modified >", timeline).filter("published =", True).filter("modified <=", bookmark ).order("-modified").fetch(PAGESIZE+1)
    if util.get_host().find('onta') > 1 and f == 'c':
        ads = Ad.all().filter("company_ad =", True).filter("modified >", timeline).filter("published =", True).filter("url IN", ['www.montao.com.br','montao']).filter("modified <=", bookmark ).order("-modified").fetch(PAGESIZE+1)
    elif util.get_host().find('onta') > 1 and f == 'p':
        ads = Ad.all().filter("company_ad =", False).filter("modified >", timeline).filter("published =", True).filter("url IN", ['www.montao.com.br','montao']).filter("modified <=", bookmark ).order("-modified").fetch(PAGESIZE+1)  


    if self.request.get('lat'):
        m=int(self.request.get('r')) if self.request.get('r') else 804670
        logging.info(m)
        lat = self.request.get('lat')
        lon = self.request.get('lon') if self.request.get('lon') else self.request.get('lng')
        ads = Ad.proximity_fetch(Ad.all().filter("modified >", timeline).filter("published =", True).filter("modified <=", bookmark ).order("-modified") ,db.GeoPt(lat, lon),max_results=PAGESIZE+1, max_distance=m)
        ads = sorted(ads, key=lambda x: x.modified, reverse=True)
    if ads and len(ads) == PAGESIZE+1:
      next = ads[-1].modified
      ads = ads[:PAGESIZE]     

    template_values = {'twittername':twittername,'request':self.request,'lat':self.request.get('lat'),'lon':self.request.get('lon'),'q':q,'w':w,'cg':cg,'t':t,'logo':logo,'ads':ads, 'next':next, 'user':users.get_current_user(), 'bookmark':bookmark,'q':q, 'user_url': users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri) if users.get_current_user() else 'login',
            'cg':category,'admin':users.is_current_user_admin(),}
    template_values.update(dict(current_user=self.current_user, facebook_app_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID))
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), dispatch)
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

UPDATE 2: I tried using the django paginator class `from paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage, EmptyPage` in this this case the following code actually pages the data set:

```
        articles = Articles.all()
        paginator = Paginator(articles,PAGESIZE)
        articles = paginator.page(page)
```

so I find this solution tempting since it's so easy and readable and hope that you can comment onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to base64 encoded your bookmark before you pass it to client.
I have tried [Your site][1], but it is impossible to answer your question clearly without the server side error message.

Moreover, as the paging article has mentioned, using datetime as bookmark directly will cause issues  while there are more than one articles posted in the same time period (in your case, the time period will be one minute). You may want to consider using this format instead.

```
2008-10-26 04:38:00|aee15ab24b7b3718596e3acce04fba85
```

or using seconds to represent the time.

```
1310427763.47|aee15ab24b7b3718596e3acce04fba85
```

> should I set it to datetime.now() if it's the first page that gets viewed?

You can get the first page results by simply ignore the modified filter.
For example:

```
if bookmark:
    suggestions = Suggestion.all().order("-when")
        .filter('when <=', bookmark).fetch(PAGESIZE+1)
else:
    suggestions = Suggestion.all().order("-when").fetch(PAGESIZE+1)
```

or using the current time as bookmark.

```
import time
bookmark = str(time.time())
```

Comment: Thank you lucemia. I should try to fins a suitable format. The way it displays now doesn't seem right. I will try the way of using seconds to represent the time but I'm not sure how to use the bookmark variable eg. should I set it to datetime.now() if it's the first page that gets viewed?

Comment: You can get the first page results with two ways. Both ways should work fine!

Comment: It will work if only I can match the time formats. I could get another way working by using a datetime object from django as described by Abdul in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014657/query-with-paging-by-cursor-causes-error-because-of-limitations-for-in-filter-i/

Answer (score 3):

[Query cursors](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Query_Cursors) are built for exactly this. You should use them instead of building your own solution.

Comment: Thank you Nick but later in my code I use the IN operator which seems to make query cursors unavailable.

Comment: @Niklas Unavailable for queries that use it, yes, but the query you posted _doesn't_ use IN.

Comment: OK either I can rework the queries that also followed to not use IN or I use datetime as bookmark until either I get rid of the IN or cursors get updated to work with IN