# Evaluating django paginator with GAE

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, pagination

Is it a good idea to add the django paginator to our google app engine project to enable pagination? It looks tempting since I otherwise fail to implement pagination though there can be hidden disadvantages. For instance the PageQuery class that we tried yesterday couldn't page SearchableModel(!) but django paginator can. Is there a better reason to use cursors instead? Now I actually can page the dataset in a simple way using a page variable but I do it with the django paginator class

`from paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage, EmptyPage`

in this this case the following code actually pages the data set:

```
        articles = Articles.all()
        paginator = Paginator(articles,PAGESIZE)
        articles = paginator.page(page)
```

so I find this solution tempting since it's so easy and readable and hope that you can comment onwards. The django file I added is
http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/paginator.py
I can still use my IN query and the code is very readable just adding the django paginator.
Am I making a mistake not using cursors and what are the disadvantages in my case?
If you want closer look at my implementation details I've posted some here [How to page the dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642707/how-to-page-the-dataset)
Thank you

--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend of mine uses it and has performance problems, I think it uses limit and offset which is not a great fit for AppEngine. The proper solution would be to use a paginator that uses cursors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will also look at pagination that uses cursors. I'm glad the django aginator is compatible though since it was easy to get working. I deployed it to my site www.koolbusiness.com/li that now can take a page parameter which is more intuitive than a cursor

Comment: I'm glad it was so easy to use the django paginator class and hope that mayeb I can have a paginator class that uses cursors but with exactly the same API as the django paginator so all I would have do to, if it works, to switch from using limit and offset to using cursors I just need an updated `paginator.py`and the API is conveivingly the same API so I wouldn't have to change the calls to the paginator.